# How to show that two subgroups of $\mathbb Z_n$ are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Consider the cyclic group $\mathbb Z_n$.
Let $d_1$ be a positive proper divisor of $n$.
Let $K_{d_1}=\{x:\gcd(x,n)=d_1\}$.

If $a,b\in K_{d_1}$, is it true that $\langle a\rangle =\langle b\rangle$?
Here $\langle a\rangle$ denotes the cylcic group generated by $a$.

**My try**:
I need to show that $\langle a\rangle\subseteq\langle b\rangle$ and then $\langle b\rangle\subseteq\langle a\rangle$.

Let $x\in \langle a\rangle$, then $x=ma$. Also $\gcd(a,n)=d_1$ so $a=kd_1$, so we have
$x=mkd_1$

I am stuck on how to show that $x\in \langle b\rangle$ from here. Please help someone.

Comment: Try it with some small examples, you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Do you know about [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)?

Comment: @Christoph; yes but dont know how to apply here, pls help

Comment: Use it to show that $\overline{d_1}\in\langle \bar a\rangle$. Since also $\bar a\in\langle \overline{d_1}\rangle$ you can conclude … (Here I used the notation $\bar x\in\mathbb Z_n$ for the equivalence class of $x\in\mathbb Z$. Just calling both $x$ is confusing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing your steps:

By [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#:%7E:text=In%20elementary%20number%20theory%2C%20B%C3%A9zout%27s%20identity%20%28also%20called,%2B%20by%20are%20exactly%20the%20multiples%20of%20d.), we know that there exist $x_0,y_0, x_1, y_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d_1 = ax_0 + ny_0 = bx_1+ny_1$ by hypothesis. So
$$ x = mkd_1 = mk( bx_1 + ny_1) = b(mkx_1) + n(mky_1) = b(mkx_1) \mod n \in \langle b \rangle$$ so we have $\langle a \rangle \subseteq \langle b \rangle$

To show the other inclusion,
comsider $x \in \langle b \rangle$ then there exist integers $m_1$ and $k_1$ such that $x = m_1k_1d_1$, similar to previous argument we have $x = a(m_1k_1x_0) \mod n \in \langle a \rangle$.